# How would you calculate expiry to update column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I'm trying to figure out the right approach for calculating the remainder days of a user subscription.

For example; user signs up December 25, 2013 for a month and unsubscribed December 29, 2013. Even though he unsubscribed 4 days after subscribing, his subscription should run on PLAN A for the next 27 days (31 day based month).

I'm thinking I would be using the created_at and updated_at of subscription model. So far I got to

**MODEL: subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save :set_expiry_date

    def set_expiry_date
        @remaining_days = Subscription.calculate(:created_at - Date.today)
        Subscription.expiry = '@remaining_days'
        Subscription.save
    end

end
```

Something like that but I'm missing something here and this might be an ugly approach. I'm guessing this gives anyone who can help small understanding what I'm after.

I would then run a rake as cron each day at 23:59 that removes 1 (day) from Subscription.expiry number in there and when it finds a 0, it would update something. That's another question though but I placed the stuff about the rake cron so you see where I'm heading with this.

Answer (score 4):

If this were my project, I would take a different approach. I would set subscription expiry to the actual expiry date rather than a decrementing integer. That makes less work for the cron and also feels like good date practice . . . you get the benefit of persisting expiration dates after the expiration, which might be handy for later data analysis. What if there is a bug in your program or your cron fails to run? By persisting the date, you can do some detailed homework or rerun your crons against a specific cohort.

If I needed to know how many days were remaining on the subscription for UI or for API responses, I could call a method on the subscription class that looks something like the remaining_days method below:

```
def set_expiry_date
    #automatically adds a month
    #http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_month
    Subscription.expiry_date = Subscription.created_at.next_month
    Subscription.save
end

def remaining_days
    expired? ? 0 : (Date.today - Subscription.expiry_date).to_i
end

def expired?
  (Date.today - Subscription.expiry_date).to_i <= 0   
end

def expired_today?
  Date.today == Subscription.expiry_date
end
```

Then, my daily cron that does something on expiration (send email beseeching the customer to come back?) would just look for subscriptions where expired_today? == true. My cron would then also ignore subscriptions that expired before today or are yet to expire.

Comment: Great idea, I see your purpose around it. Just fantastic. Am I putting this in the controller or model?

Comment: All of this logic should be in the model. I like to think of models as a pretty simple class that has things and can do things. In this case, the subscription can set an expiration date and has simple math methods on that expiration date. Changes on individual instances of classes would likely happen through the controller; so invoking the set_expiry_date method would likely happen through a controller. But, if this is a straight API call to set an expiration date, you may not need a controller at all -- you could just look up a user's subscription and set the expiry_date.

Comment: mind showing me how you would write a controller and model for this. I'm getting few issues in my model having all this in there. Not sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: Sure. Can you tell me more about when you would want to update the expiration date? What would initiate the plan expiration? Would that expiration happen in response to some rails UI or to an API? We don't necessarily need a controller method for this.

Comment: basically we have a controller that acts on someone clicking the subscription button, it then connects to stripe for CC stuff and returns using the controller and saves a token, that's pretty much it, token gets saved in Subscription DB. Both controller and model are named subscription.rb and subscriptions_controller.rb When someone cancels the subscription, we have the controller and model delete the subscription out of stripe and remove the subscription in DB.

Comment: however, I wanted to change that because deleting the subscription means the user is dropped to our free plan, even though he paid for a month. Not a good model. So I was thinking that rather then deleting the subscription record for that user, we should update the subscription with expiry_date, like in your example. Then have a cron rake each day and when it finds an expired record entry, it removes that subscription and runs something else too, like sends an email to us and client. Your answer is beautiful, I just get error that expiry_date= isn't defined yet, and so on.

Comment: Oh, I see two potential bugs in the model, now that you've mentioned the error. It sounds like we need to make the expiry_date attribute accessible on the model. See [ruby docs for attr accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) You might also like [this tutorial](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) about attribute accessors.

Comment: Another thing, not every subscription will have an expiration date. So the expired_today? should change to !expiry_date.nil? && Date.today == Subscription.expiry_date

This same problem will occur anywhere that you are inspecting the expiry_date, so you refactor logic accordingly in the above sample.

Comment: So something like this then; https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1088b339ac7ac5f86db and in our controller I should just run @subscription.set_expiry_date after all the stripe stuff happens?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44831/discussion-between-user2419316-and-s-gray)